# copy_if vs saving sequences and using copy

Tags: c++, vector, copy, stl-algorithm

Why copy_if works slower then copy

I'm currently working on my OpenGL graphics engine. And I was trying to figure out the best way to pass big amount of objects to GPU for instanced drawing. The biggest problem for me is that some objects can be dead, so I created a small test.

Here is a simple struct that I was testing (in real app it would be position + colors, etc.)

```
struct foo
{
   bool is_active = false;
   float value = 0.0f;
};
```

After this I created these containers:

```
// All data
std::vector<foo> data_vector;
// Data that is only active
std::vector<foo> active_vector;
using distance_t = vector<foo>::iterator::difference_type;
// List of segments, so that if we have 10 elements where
// only the 5th is not active it is going to look like that
// { {0,5}, {6, 10} }
std::list<pair<distance_t, distance_t>> active_segments;
```

Reserved space for 1,000,000 elements in vectors. Filled *data_vector* with all true values. Filled the list as well in order to ignore allocation time. And tested the speed of these 3 copy functions with *high_resolution_clock*

```
// First method
// For all true values *active_segments* has only one element with 
// {0, 1000000}
for_each(active_segments.begin(), active_segments.end(), 
              [&active_vector, data_vector](auto current)
    {
      copy(data_vector.begin() + current.first, 
      data_vector.begin() + current.second, 
      std::back_inserter(active_vector));
    });

// Second method
copy_if(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(),
        std::back_inserter(active_vector), 
        [](const foo &current)
        {
           return current.is_active;
        });

// Third method
copy(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), 
     std::back_inserter(active_vector));
```

Obviously *copy* was the fastest one with 18024 microseconds. But I was surprised that *copy_if* is faster(27777 microseconds), then the first method(33278 microseconds).

I don't understand why this is happening. I wanted to have some extra memory allocation but increased copy speed, but in result I have method that is slower even in the best conditions.

Comment: you should also capture `data_vector` by reference.

Comment: What happens if you use a std::vector instead of std::list for active_segments?

Comment: Try `active_vector.insert(active_vector.end(), data_vector.begin() + current.first, data_vector.begin() + current.second)`. That should be even faster as it avoids `push_back` call per element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you have a combination of (at least) two factors leading to the problem.

The first is a real problem: in your lambda, you're capturing `data_vector` by value instead of by reference, so you're copying the whole input array, then copy data from that copy to the result.

The second is mostly specific to benchmarking: cache warming. If I fix the lambda so its captures by reference, your method 1 still runs significantly slower than the other two methods. **But** if I add a simple cache-warming loop ahead of it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    active_vector.push_back(data_vector[i]);
```

...then I can run all three after that, and they all run at close enough to the same speed that I can no longer be certain that one is faster than another.

On the other hand, I believe this also indicates that the whole exercise is kind of pointless--although `copy_if` should theoretically be a tiny bit slower than `copy` (on a per-element basis), I can't find any significant difference between the two. I suspect in most cases, memory bandwidth is the limiting factor, and the extra processing time to figure out whether to copy something is simply lost in the noise. In fact, sometimes, the second version (using `copy_if`) is coming out the fastest, and the third (using `copy`) the slowest:

```
method 1:   3,295us
method 2:   3,178us
method 3:   3,839us
```

Just for what it's worth, here's the code as I ran it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    bool is_active = true;
    float value = 0.0f;
};

int main() {

    const int size = 1'000'000;

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    // All data
    std::vector<foo> data_vector(size);
    // Data that is only active
    std::vector<foo> active_vector;

    using distance_t = std::vector<foo>::iterator::difference_type;
    // List of segments, so that if we have 10 elements where
    // only the 5th is not active it is going to look like that
    // { {0,5}, {6, 10} }
    std::vector<std::pair<distance_t, distance_t>> active_segments;

    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Warm the cache:
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        active_vector.push_back(data_vector[i]);

    {
        active_segments.emplace_back(0, size);

        active_vector.clear();
        active_vector.reserve(size);
        auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();

        for_each(active_segments.begin(), active_segments.end(),
            [&active_vector, &data_vector](auto current)
        {
            copy(data_vector.begin() + current.first,
                data_vector.begin() + current.second,
                std::back_inserter(active_vector));
        });
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << "method 1:   " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "us\n";
    }

    {
        active_vector.clear();
        active_vector.reserve(size);
        auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();
        // Second method
        copy_if(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(),
            std::back_inserter(active_vector),
            [](const foo &current)
        {
            return current.is_active;
        });
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "method 2:   " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "us\n";
    }

    {
        active_vector.clear();
        active_vector.reserve(size);
        auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();
        copy(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(),
            std::back_inserter(active_vector));
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << "method 3:   " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "us\n";
    }
}
```

There is one more point that should probably be considered: do you still need the elements in `data_vector` that are no longer active? If you no longer need them, you can use `std::remove_if` to move all the active elements to the beginning of the collection, and then erase from there to the end.

```
auto e = std::remove_if(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), 
                       [](auto const &e) {return e.is_active; });
data_vector.erase(e, data_vector.end());
```

A quick test with a 50% chance of each element being marked active or inactive shows this running around twice the speed of copying the active elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really missed the reference. Now I have better results with the first method in the array with all true values. But with randomly assigned boolean values it is different. I'll try to check out the warming up of the cache. And i missed that I was using 10 millions instead of 1 million, so my time wasn't correct but the idea is the same.